# How to check constructor arguments and throw an exception or make an assertion in a default constructor in Scala?

Tags: scala, exception, constructor, assert

I would like to check constructor arguments and refuse to construct throwing `IllegalArgumentException` in case the arguments set is not valid (the values don't fit in expected constraints). How to code this in Scala?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

In Scala, the whole body of the class is your primary constructor, so you can add your validation logic there.

```
scala> class Foo(val i: Int) {
     |   if(i < 0) 
     |     throw new IllegalArgumentException("the number must be non-negative.")
     | }
defined class Foo

scala> new Foo(3)
res106: Foo = Foo@3bfdb2

scala> new Foo(-3)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the number must be positive.
```

Scala provides a utility method [`require`](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_9_1_final/src//library/scala/Predef.scala#L143) that lets you write the same thing more concisely as follows:

```
class Foo(val i: Int) {
  require(i >= 0, "the number must be non-negative.")
}
```

A better approach might be to provide a factory method that gives a `scalaz.Validation[String, Foo]` instead of throwing an exception. (Note: requires Scalaz)

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

class Foo private(val i: Int)

object Foo {
  def apply(i: Int) = {
    if(i < 0)
      failure("number must be non-negative.")
    else
      success(new Foo(i))
  }
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class Foo
defined module Foo

scala> Foo(3)
res108: scalaz.Validation[java.lang.String,Foo] = Success(Foo@114b3d5)

scala> Foo(-3)
res109: scalaz.Validation[java.lang.String,Foo] = Failure(number must be non-negative.)
```

Comment: Throwing exceptions in constructors is less than ideal. Whenever I need a type with restrictions on the domains of any of its constructor parameters, I make the constructor private and force instantiation through a factory that applies the constraints and either throws (via `require`, usually) or returns `Try[ConstrainedType]`.

Comment: I think you mean that the message in require should say `non-negative`.

Answer (score 19):

```
scala> class Foo(arg: Int) {
     |   require (arg == 0)
     | }
defined class Foo

scala> new Foo(0)
res24: Foo = Foo@61ecb73c

scala> new Foo(1)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed
```

Comment: Nice! What a perfect answer to the question. Can you elaborate a little (or link to elaboration) on the details of how `require` works?

Comment: Here's how does `require` work, @dan-burton ;-) http://pastebin.com/rJQfTCX9 It just throws `new IllegalArgumentException("requirement failed")` if the argument is false. The whole idea of using `require` instead of just throwing the exception yourselves is to make your code prettier and better suitable for static analysis (which seems not implemented yet).