# Why is it illegal to call mean on this 3x2 matrix of doubles in Scala Breeze?

Tags: scala, scalala

I am new to Breeze (formerly Scalala), and can't figure out why the following simple program throws an exception.  i am using Scala 2.9.2 and Breeze 0.1:

```
import breeze.linalg._
val m = DenseMatrix((3.0, 1.0, 2.0), (-2.0, 1.0, 3.0))
val n = mean(m, Axis._1)
```

It works as expected if I use a 2x2 or a 3x2 matrix, but a 2x3 matrix causes the following exception:

```
-- org.jblas ERROR Couldn't load copied link file: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\daved\AppData\Local\Temp\jblas8588491482847885553jblas.dll: Can't find dependent libraries.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
    at breeze.linalg.package$$anon$1.apply$mcD$sp(package.scala:203)
    at breeze.linalg.package$$anon$1.apply(package.scala:196)
    at breeze.linalg.package$$anon$1.apply(package.scala:186)
    at breeze.linalg.DenseVector.ureduce(DenseVector.scala:91)
    at breeze.linalg.Tensor$$anon$1.apply(Tensor.scala:149)
    at breeze.generic.UReduceable$class.apply$mcD$sp(URFunc.scala:56)
    at breeze.linalg.Tensor$$anon$1.apply$mcD$sp(Tensor.scala:148)
    at breeze.generic.URFunc$mcD$sp$class.apply$mcD$sp(URFunc.scala:32)
    at breeze.linalg.package$$anon$1.apply$mcD$sp(package.scala:186)
    at breeze.generic.URFunc$mcD$sp$$anonfun$apply$mcD$sp$1.apply(URFunc.scala:36)
    at breeze.linalg.LowPriorityDenseMatrix1$$anon$17.apply(DenseMatrix.scala:444)
    at breeze.linalg.LowPriorityDenseMatrix1$$anon$17.apply(DenseMatrix.scala:440)
    at breeze.generic.URFunc$mcD$sp$class.apply$mcD$sp(URFunc.scala:36)
    at breeze.linalg.package$$anon$1.apply$mcD$sp(package.scala:186)
    at com.tennisedge.opencv.BreezePlay$delayedInit$body.apply(BreezePlay.scala:24)
```

Comment: Please show where in the documentation your input is legal, until then this is a bug in your code, not Breeze's. See http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault.html

Comment: In the scaladoc for Breeze at http://www.scalanlp.org/api/#breeze.linalg.package it indicates `mean` is a `URFunc`.  Since a DenseMatrix[Double] is reduceable, it should be legal to call this.

If it is a bug in my code, I change my question to be "Which matrices are legal to call `mean` on"

Comment: so variable m is valid, instantiated object and the problem is in the 3 line (mean) - correct?

Comment: This works fine for me on osx using SBT. It sounds like you have a dependency problem since it can't find jblas, or at least it can't access it.

Comment: yes, this was my 1 guess, but when I read that it was working with some other dimensions... - not sure ...

Comment: Are correctly configured native libraries a  requirement for correct operation of Breeze?

Comment: Ok, so debugging down into this, it looks to me like a bug in DenseMatrix.  Line 449:
  implicit def canCollapseCols[V, R:ClassManifest] = new CanCollapseAxis[DenseMatrix[V], Axis._1.type, DenseVector[V], R, DenseVector[R]] {
    def apply(from: DenseMatrix[V], axis: Axis._1.type)(f: (DenseVector[V]) => R): DenseVector[R] = {
      val result = DenseVector.zeros[R](from.rows)
      val t = from.t
      for(r <- 0 until from.cols) {
        result(r) = f(t(::, r))
      }
      result
    }
  }
The `0 until from.cols` should be `0 until t.cols`

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is a bug in Breeze.  In particular, the `DenseMatrix` `canCollapseCols` implicit conversion.

If I define my own implicit conversion in the local file, everyting works as expected:

```
implicit def myCanCollapseCols[V, R:ClassManifest] = new CanCollapseAxis[DenseMatrix[V], Axis._1.type, DenseVector[V], R, DenseVector[R]] {
  def apply(from: DenseMatrix[V], axis: Axis._1.type)(f: (DenseVector[V]) => R): DenseVector[R] = {
    val result = DenseVector.zeros[R](from.rows)
    val t = from.t
    for(r <- 0 until t.cols) { // BUG WAS HERE: was from.cols in original defintion.
      result(r) = f(t(::, r))
    }
    result
  }
}

val m = breeze.linalg.DenseMatrix((3.0, 1.0, 2.0), (-2.0, 1.0, 3.0))
val n = breeze.linalg.mean(m, breeze.linalg.Axis._1)
```

This is still there in head, so I will create a pull request for it in GitHub to fix.  In the meantime I can just use my own implicit conversion.

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect example (referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14865528/best-way-to-validate-and-extend-constructor-parameters-in-scala-2-10/14865697#14865697)) of the problem with exceptions thrown in constructors! What is masquerading as a dependency problem is really an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` that was encountered in a constructor that was called during on-demand class loading. It's often very perplexing. (This is my "favorite" (most infamous) consequence of throwing exceptions in constructors.)

At least that's what it appears to be to me. I can't be sure, really.

Comment: do you think your answer is valid even if question was based on Scala 2.9.2 and Breeze 0.1 ?

Comment: @xhudik: I know nothing of Breeze / Scalala (I've heard of the old name) but I don't think my answer is in any way specific to the Scala version or the specific 3rd-party library (native or otherwise) in question.

Comment: @Kirk: Class-loading is usually triggered by a constructor call, right?

Comment: Hmm, weird. This edit appears to be confused with another. I'll revert it