# Is it possible to create value classes with invariants?

Tags: scala

Suppose I wanted to declare in an method declaration somewhere that it could only take a string that was known not to be empty, and not incur any runtime cost for doing so.
Something like:

```
class NonEmptyString(val s: String) extends AnyVal {}
object NonEmptyString {
    def apply(s: String) {
        require(!s.isEmpty)
        new NonEmptyString(s)
    }
}
```

Would seem to do the trick, but it would in theory allow someone to just new-up another one as required.

If it were not a value class, I could simply put the check in the constructor, but value classes aren't able to have constructors:

```
scala> class NonEmptyString(val s: String) extends AnyVal { require(!s.isEmpty) }
<console>:7: error: this statement is not allowed in value class
    class NonEmptyString(val s: String) extends AnyVal { require(!s.isEmpty) }
```

There's a couple of places where this would be a useful technique in my current project, has anyone come up with a good way to add invariants to value classes?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169691/how-to-check-constructor-arguments-and-throw-an-exception-or-make-an-assertion-i

Comment: You could just make the constructor `private` on the `class`. If you want compile-time invariants though... Only way to do that would probably be through macros, but I don't know nearly enough about them to give you any hints.

Comment: For a runtime invariant check, I have thought it would be nice to allow a ctor body (with the require) that is run before all usages.

Comment: @Jaranda Thanks, but not a duplicate - I'll edit to make the difference clearer.